# C#/Xamarin: not able to access override UIPickerViewModel class Parameters

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have an issue with an class that I extended `UIPickerViewModel` with.
I have a string to access the selected value from the picker view. i.e. `public string SelectedValue {get; set;}`. Then in my class with the ViewDidLoad() method I set the model on the picker view to a new instance of that class.
When the user picks the value and clicks a Done Button I want to access the value they've picked and close the picker view like this:

```
    private void GalaxyDoneClicked()
    {
        this.galaxyTextField.Text = this.galaxyPicker.Model.SelectedValue;    
    }
```

But I'm getting an error of : `UIPickerViewModel does not contain a definition for 'SelectedValue' and no extension method 'SelectedValue' accepting a first argument of type 'UIPickerViewModel' could be found ( are you missing  a using directive or an assembly reference?)`.

I'm pretty new to C# and Xamarin, any help here would be greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the `galaxyPicker` to your custom class:

```
if ( galaxyPicker is MyCustomPickerViewModelClass myCustomPicker )
{
   this.galaxyTextField.Text = this.galaxyPicker.Model.SelectedValue; 
}
```

Where `MyCustomPickerViewModelClass` is the custom class you derived from `UIPickerViewModel`

Answer (score 1):

That helped Martin. It ended up being

```
    if(galaxyPicker.Model is MyCustomPickerViewModelClass myCustomPickerModel)
    {
        this.galaxyTextField.Text = myCustomPickerModel.SelectedValue;
    }
```